# Error creating CSR in openSSL using SubjectAltName 'OtherName"

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate, csr

I'm receiving an error when trying to create a CSR that is using v3_req extensions

The errors I receive are:

```
Error Loading request extension section v3_req
37232:error:0D06407A:asn1 encoding routines:a2d_ASN1_OBJECT:first num too large:./crypto/asn1/a_object.c:109:
37232:error:22075093:X509 V3 routines:v2i_GENERAL_NAME_ex:othername error:./crypto/x509v3/v3_alt.c:502:
37232:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:./crypto/x509v3/v3_conf.c:93:name=subjectAltName, value=otherName:Principal Name;UTF8:1999999999123456@test
```

my openSSL cnf section looks like:

```
[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = otherName:UTF8:Principal Name = 1999999999123456@test
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a csr (everything else with my script and cnf works fine, just when adding in the SAN portion) that has a SAN of other name and "Principal Name" that would look like this when viewing the cert fields

```
Other Name: Principal Name = 1999999999123456@test
```

I assume i have the v3_req and otherName setup portion incorrect but I cannot find the right documentation on usage of custom fields for SAN/OtherName. if i use this with DNS or IP, it works like you would expect.

Comment: *"I cannot find the right documentation on usage of custom fields for SAN/OtherName"* - see [x509v3_config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man5/x509v3_config.html): *" the value should be the __OID followed by a semicolon__ and the content in standard ASN1_generate_nconf(3) format"*. As for the correct OID see [here](http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3&action=display).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I had found that same section, but when trying to use that format, as in the example above I receive the errors mentioned. How should the format be for the oid and content to get the result I’m looking for?  I assume I’m messing up the oid and the asn1_generate_nconf(3) formatting

Comment: *"but when trying to use that format, as in the example above I receive the errors mentioned."* - the example from your question does not use the documented format (no OID, no semicolon). If you feel that you've followed the documentation then please adjust your question to show this and show the error messages you get when using the documented format. There is also an example in the documentation you can follow.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you for the clarification on the format and link to the correct OID I needed. I was unsure of the format for that and didn't realize that "Principal Name" was the UPN. Appreciate the assistance. If you post the format and OID as a reply i can mark that as an answer for you.

Comment: I'm glad to point you into the right direction. Given that you now hopefully have a solution I recommend to write an answer yourself and thus help others who stumble over similar problems in the future. It is actually not that unusual to answer ones own question.

Answer (score 3):

after reviewing the documenation that Steffen Ullrich mentioned and checking the formatting, the correct format for adding the alt name is:

```
[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = otherName:1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:1999999999123456@TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

I had unicode blanks and other stuff in the config-file, which of course messed everything up. In case someone might suspect a similar thing, this command found them:

`pcregrep --color='auto' -n "[\x80-\xFF]"` 
from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/find-non-ascii-chars).